# SPAudit.WriteAuditEvent overloads unavailable

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

I am doing some work currently that requires custom Audit events to be written. The **SPAudit** class has several overloads available for the `WriteAuditEvent` function, but only one of them is a static function according to this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spaudit.writeauditevent?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sharepoint-server#overloads)

As I understand, I would need to create an instance of the **SPAudit** class to be able to use the non-static functions that are defined but it seems like there is no definition of the constructor available.

If I try to do something like

```
 SPAudit auditEvent = new SPAudit();
```

It tell me it does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments. I do not see anything in the documentation that has the correct signature for the constructor and intellisense is not giving me any suggestions.

I have to assume I am missing something really obvious here, or I am not understanding something at a very basic level. Can anyone help shed some light on this?

Specifically I am trying to use the

```
WriteAuditEvent(String, String, Int32, String)
```

overload which is defined as:

```
public:
bool WriteAuditEvent(System::String ^ eventName, System::String ^ eventSource, 
                     int userId, System::String ^ xmlData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found an answer to my own question here. There is an **Audit** property on the **SPSite** object so we can create the object with the following

```
SPAudit auditEvent = site.Audit;
```

With that object created, I seem to be able to access all the other methods I was after.